# DDD - Aggregate holding logic of child entity vs using child entity repository

Tags: design, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to come up with a DDD solution. Let's say we have two entities: User and Post and User is a root aggregate.

```
User {
    List<Post> posts;
    public List<Post> getPosts() {
         return posts;
    }
}
```

It sounds good to only use UserRepository to retrieve a User, along with its posts, but what about returning its posts in an specific order (e.g. by date).

Does it still make sense to have a method *getPosts(Order order)* or *getPostsByOrder(Order order)*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn’t pollute a domain with queries. A domain is really useful for handling commands, but not so much for queries. Too slow and not necessary for queries, because when commands persist the new state, you can simply query the database.

Comment: I would question the wisdom of having a `public List<Post> getPosts()` method at all.